# React Router - Private Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
function App() {

  const view = useSelector(viewsSelector);

  const isAuth = () => {
    if(view === ''){
        return false;
    }
    if(view === 'welcome'){
        return true;
    }
}

  console.log(isAuth());

  const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  return(
      <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        isAuth()
          ? <Component {...props}/>
          : <Redirect to='/Login'/>
      )}/>
   )
  }
  
  return(
    <Router>
      <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login}/>
          <Route path='/About' component={About}/>
          <Route path='/Contact' component={Contact}/>
          <Route path='/Help' component={Help}/>
          <PrivateRoute path='/Welcome' component={Welcome}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  )

}
```

I am working with Private or Protected Route.

`isAuth()` works when it is `false` you can not go anywhere except the `Login`

but `isAuth()` changes from `false` to `true`, It does not redirect the route to `path='./Welcome`

How can I redirect it when the `isAuth()` changes?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the `isAuth` result to the `PrivateRoute`, otherwise it won't know when `isAuth` has changed.

```
function App() {
    const view = useSelector(viewsSelector);

    const isAuth = () => {
        if (view === "") {
            return false;
        }
        if (view === "welcome") {
            return true;
        }
    };

    console.log(isAuth());

    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, canView, ...rest }) => {
        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={(props) =>
                    canView ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/Login" />
                }
            />
        );
    };

    return (
        <Router>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/About" component={About} />
                <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route path="/Help" component={Help} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/Welcome" component={Welcome} canView={isAuth()} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think the same way, and we go in the right direction. Thank you so much for your answer!
We need something like a trigger for redirecting the Route.
I tried your way, but it still keeps me on the Login Page, and don't want to redirect me to Welcome